# Need mod_rewrite condition and rule to replace ".com" with ".org" on 1 virtual host

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have a series of mod_rewrite directives (shown below as Code 1) that run every server request through a custom PHP app.

Code 1

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app/core.php [L,NC,QSA]
```

Before I get to the last step in the mod_rewrites, I need to change any request to mydomain.com to mydomain.org. Code 2 below shows what I am thinking but it does not work. The request gives me 500 Internal Server error.

Code 2

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^ http://mydomain.org%{REQUEST_URI}
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app/core.php [L,NC,QSA]
```

Can someone offer a suggestion? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asume your site is reachable by two domains, but you want all request to your site redirected to one of them. Then the correct code is:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.org/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

You should place that code directly after the redirect line.

The second line makes sure that there is no redirect if no Host is given (to prevent a redirect loop in that case).

The [R=permanent,L] in the third line makes it a permanent redirect and prevents any further rule processing. The other rules will be processed once the redirect has taken place.

---

The full file would then be:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.org/$1 [R=permanent,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app/core.php [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks @Chronial. Your assumption is correct according to the way you stated it. So does the entire snipit of directives look like this:
`Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.org/$1 [R=permanent,L]RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app/core.php [L,NC,QSA]`

Comment: @Chronial...I can't seem to format my comment to reveal readable code so look at the next answer for my revised directives and tell me if that is the solution I should use.

Comment: As i said you have to place my code **after** the RewriteBase command. Updated my answer to include the full code.

Comment: Ok thanks @Chronial. When I read what you said above "You should place that code directly after the redirect line" I wasn't sure that "redirect line" actually meant rewrite base. I am learning :)

Comment: Well, it did not work. Other, unrelated virtual hosts on the server showed as a repetitive series of redirect messages in the browser status bar and never resolved the page. mydomain.com actually showed the temp landing page which it was not supposed to do -- it was supposed to show the .org site. And mydomain.org just sat at a white screen with the progress bar slowing moving and I killed the whole thing after is sat there for about 30 clock seconds. So I think I will just move on. Thanks for taking a shot at it.

Comment: Sry for the confusion I caused ^^. Under no circumstances should there by any random virtual hosts showing up. You might want to have a look at the actual redirects that take place. This can be done in firefox, by opening the web console (ctrl+shift+k). But what browser are you using? None of the modern ones should freeze, because they have a redirection limit built in.

Comment: No problem @Chronial. I ended up taking a different path and I used a PHP script to test the _SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] and then rewrite the headers. So I have my solution working as I needed it too. Initially I wanted to keep it a pre-processor solution via Apache Directives, but opted out simply due to the complexity and my lack of technical expertise with mod_rewrite.

Comment: Whoa...talk about learning. I just peeked at the Ctrl+Shift+k thing. Wow is that cool. Never knew about that. I have a lot of FF plugins installed that I use to test and troubleshoot my development stuff. This one is really, really neat. Thanks for that heads-up @Chronial!

Answer (score 0):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.org/$1 [R=permanent,L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app/core.php [L,NC,QSA]
```